# Visualizing Blogger's data

Tags: blogger

Is there a way to view the **data** used on Blogger's html?

For instance, I'm trying to change code for only a **specific** page. So far I've used the `cond='data:view.isHomepage'` expression to do that, but now I want to change code for a page that's not the homepage, but only that one page.

So I tried putting a `<script>console.log(data:view.description);</script>` in my code to then know what to condition the `data:view.description` against. This doesn't work, but I was wondering if there's anything I could do to view the actual data. This would allow me to work with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target pages other than the homepage, use `cond='not data:view.isHomepage'`

If you want to change code for only a specific page. check url like this

```
<b:if cond='data:view.url == "yourPageUrl"> ... </b:if>
```

Comment: So in this case that wouldn't be enough because I don't want the change to apply to any of the other non homepage pages. Only this one page

Comment: What about using URL to get your page as in my ex ?

Comment: As it turns out this doesn't help me in this specific case, because the url changes from time to time (the page is the Older Messages page), but as long as I find a way to have "yourPageUrl" being put there dynamically (probably looking at how they put the link in the Older Messages button), it will be a good solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there is a way to view all that data with

```
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      if (typeof _WidgetManager !== "undefined") {
        var data = _WidgetManager._GetAllData();
        console.log(data);
      }
    }, false);
</script>
```

but as it turns out `data.view.description` doesn't give any distinction between the pages.
So the question remains, is there a way to distinguish every page?